# Track Multiple Inquires on Single Customer in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL and am trying to build a basic contact form tracking database.  Please excuse my terminology.

I know how to connect, insert variables but I am trying to figure out how to handle inserting a checkbox submission into the database and have it relate to the customer that submitted it.

A basic example:

HTML form: 
Name
Email
Area of Interest

The Area of Interest part of the checkbox has 5 options.  I need them to be able to check multiple checkbox's and then have that data inserted and tracked in a database.

Do I need multiple tables?  If so, how do I relate the two for the purposes of future reporting on the information?

I hope this makes sense.  I am stumped.

---

Great Examples...Thanks.  I found many typos in my own and have corrected them and I have added some fields and renamed to fit my needs but still run into the same
Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object error

Please take a look

```
<?php 
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","flyoasis_admin","oasis225826","flyoasis_main");

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$email_address=$_POST['email_address'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$refer=$_POST['refer'];

$first_name=$mysqli->real_escape_string($first_name);
$last_name=$mysqli->real_escape_string($last_name);
$email_address=$mysqli->real_escape_string($email_address);
$phone=$mysqli->real_escape_string($phone);
$refer=$mysqli->real_escape_string($refer);
$interest=array();

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'contacts2'('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'phone', 'refer')    VALUES('".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$email_address."','".$phone."','".$refer."')");
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT 'id' FROM 'contacts2' WHERE 'email_address'='".$email_address."'");
$result=$result->fetch_assoc();
$customer_id=$result['id'];

$sql="";
foreach ($_POST['interest'] as $interest) {
$interest=$mysqli->real_escape_string($interest);
$sql.="('".$customer_id."','".$interest."'),";
}
$sql=substr($sql,0,-1);

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'interest_areas'('customer_id','interest') VALUES".$sql);

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I really appreciate your help thus far.

Answer (score 2):

I would have this SQL table setup:

```
id,name,email
--------------
1,user224,user224@example.com
2,dave,dave@example.com
```

The create table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32),
  `email` varchar(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_email` (`email`)
);
```

Then in another table, I would keep all the customer interests:

```
id,customer_id,interest
-----------------------
1,1,Golf
2,1,Badminton
3,1,Soccer
4,2,Badminton
```

As you can see, user244's interests are golf, badminton, and soccer while dave's interest is badminton.
You can create this table with:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_areas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11),
  `interest` varchar(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `customer_areas_customer_id_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now, onto the fun part. We need a html form that can handle multiple checkboxes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gathering Info</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="golf"> Golf<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="soccer"> Soccer<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="badminton"> Badminton<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On to the backend:

```
<?php
//assuming you checked $_POST content already

$mysqli=new Mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password","database");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email']

$name=$mysqli->real_escape_string($name);
$email=$mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
$interests=array();

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `customers`(`name`,`email`) VALUES('".$name."','".$email."')");
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `customers` WHERE `email`='".$email."'");
$result=$result->fetch_assoc();
$customer_id=$result['id'];

$sql="";
foreach ($_POST['interest'] as $interest) {
    $interest=$mysqli->real_escape_string($interest);
    $sql.="(".$customer_id.",'".$interest."'),";
}
$sql=substr($sql,0,-1);

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `customer_areas`(`customer_id`,`interest`) VALUES".$sql);
?>
```

Comment: I think the ID's in your interest table should be 1,2,3,4 not 1,1,1,1 right?

Comment: You should add the customer first, get their id, then add their interests along with the customer_id (get the id from when you added it). Would you like an example? I'll make one if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I successfully added the two tables however I thought I knew how to add the data.  I have the contact form built and posting correctly to the 'customers' table, but I can't add to the interest table.  If I add a second INSERT INTO statement it skips the customer table and just adds to the interests table.  

Will the customer_id match the id in the customer table automatically?  How is coded in the VALUES part of the php

INSERT INTO (id, customer_id, interests) VALUES......?

Comment: Hello! I have added some php example, you need to insert the customer first, then get the customer's id, then insert all the customer interests along with the id that you just got.

Comment: Great example...I am learning fast.  Only problem I am running into is that I receive a Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in relation to your line 15 above.

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce your error. I manually used preset data to test. `$name="dave";`, `$email="dave@example.com";` and `$_POST['interest']=array("golf","soccer");`

Comment: Make sure all the tables exists, `customers` and `customer_interests`. Use `SHOW TABLES` to see if they are there.

Comment: Please see the edit above.  I modified the table and fields to fit my needs however no luck....

Comment: Got it working...just rebuilt from scratch instead of modifying my current script.  A amateur revolution...it will fail if you have fields in your form that you don't want to add to database.  So I just added all the form fields and it worked.  I am sure there is a work around for this but at least it works for now.

Now I just have to re-add all my validation and such.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need a customer table. Related to the checkboxes you could do one of two things;
either have 5 columns in customer which are the areas of interest or have abother table called customerInterests. If you have another table you will have 2 columns ( customerId, area) . For every interest a customer has you would have one row. For how to read the checkbox values a php tutorial is sufficient such as: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html